# Parse integrating third party services

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm currently following the tutorial https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-with-third-party-services

In the module, the sendEmail function is set like so:

```
sendEmail: function(params, options) {
  return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://api:" + key + "@" + url + "/" + domain + "/messages",
    body: params,
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    if (options && options.success) {
      options.success(httpResponse);
    }
  }, function(httpResponse) {
    if (options && options.error) {
      options.error(httpResponse);
    }
  });
}
```

Whenever I run the function with curl and try to console.log the options hash, the options hash is always undefined.

The consequence is that I can't get the httpResponse object in the callback

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendEmailToUser", function(request, response) {
  client.sendEmail({
    to: "email@example.com",
    from: "MyMail@CloudCode.com",
    subject: "Hello from Parse!",
    text: "Using Parse and My Mail Module is great!"
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    response.success("Email sent!");
  }, function(httpResponse) {
    console.error(httpResponse);
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  });
});
```

How can I get the httpResponse object in the callbacks above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to return the result you get, then it would keep passing to next success/error handler

```
sendEmail: function(params, options) {
  return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    ...
  }).then(function(httpResponse) {
    if (options && options.success) {
      options.success(httpResponse);
    }
    return httpResponse
  }, function(httpResponse) {
    if (options && options.error) {
      options.error(httpResponse);
    }
    return httpResponse
  });
}
```